# Smoothing resized images in Python (How to Think Like a Computer Scientist)

Tags: python, image, smoothing

I am stuck on this exercise provided by ["How To Think Like A Computer Scientist"] (http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/thinkcspy/MoreAboutIteration/Exercises.html):

> After you have scaled an image too much it looks blocky. One way of
>   reducing the blockiness of the image is to replace each pixel with the
>   average values of the pixels around it. This has the effect of
>   smoothing out the changes in color. Write a function that takes an
>   image as a parameter and smooths the image. Your function should
>   return a new image that is the same as the old but smoothed.

Here's my source code:

```
def smooth(img):
for i in range(img.getWidth()):
    for j in range(img.getHeight()):
        #first step: get surrounding pixels
        #top pixel
        ptopcenter = img.getPixel(i,j-1)
        ptopleft = img.getPixel(i-1,j-1)
        ptopright = img.getPixel(i+1,j-1)

        #center pixel
        pcent = img.getPixel(i,j)
        pcentleft = img.getPixel(i-1,j)
        pcentright = img.getPixel(i+1,j)

        #bottom pixel
        pbotcenter = img.getPixel(i,j+1)
        pbotleft = img.getPixel(i-1,j+1)
        pbotright = img.getPixel(i+1,j+1)

        #second step: average pixels
        p1Red = ptopcenter.getRed()
        p1Blue = ptopcenter.getBlue()
        p1Green = ptopcenter.getGreen()

        p2Red = ptopcenter.getRed()
        p2Blue = ptopcenter.getBlue()
        p2Green = ptopcenter.getGreen()

        p3Red = ptopright.getRed()
        p3Blue = ptopright.getRed()
        p3Green = ptopright.getRed()

        p4Red = pcentleft.getRed()
        p4Blue = pcentleft.getBlue()
        p4Green = pcentleft.getGreen()

        p5Red = pcentright.getRed()
        p5Blue = pcentright.getBlue()
        p5Green = pcentright.getGreen()

        p6Red = pbotleft.getRed()
        p6Blue = pbotleft.getBlue()
        p6Green = pbotleft.getGreen()

        p7Red = pbotcenter.getRed()
        p7Blue = pbotcenter.getBlue()
        p7Green = pbotcenter.getGreen()

        p8Red = pbotright.getRed()
        p8Blue = pbotright.getBlue()
        p8Green = pbotright.getGreen()

        #average all the colors
        pavgRed = (p1Red + p2Red + p3Red + p4Red + p5Red + p6Red + p7Red + p8Red)/8
        pavgBlue = (p1Blue + p2Blue + p3Blue + p4Blue + p5Blue + p6Blue + p7Blue + p8Blue)/8
        pavgGreen = (p1Green + p2Green + p3Green + p4Green + p5Green + p6Green + p7Green + p8Green)/8

        pcent.setRed(pavgRed)
        pcent.setGreen(pavgGreen)
        pcent.setBlue(pavgBlue)
```

Comment: Without actually testing it or looking very deeply it seems the only thing missing is to actually load the new pixels into a buffer and then write that buffer to an image file.

Comment: You may want to read this blog post: http://blog.uploadcare.com/pillow-2-7-extended-release-notes/

Comment: You are updating the image pixel by pixel, and don't keep a copy of the original image.  After you smooth the pixel at (0, 0), you should use its original value, not its new value, when smoothing the neighboring pixels at (0, 1), (1, 0) and (1, 1).